# .git/info/exclude not excluding an untracked file

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

No matter if I create the file before or after adding it to the exclude file, it never ignores it.

```
$: cat ./.git/info/exclude

/*.php
/license.txt
/wp-admin
/wp-includes
/wp-content/themes/impact/page-test.php
wp-content/themes/impact/page-test.php
page-test.php

$: git status

On branch development
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/development'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    wp-content/themes/impact/page-test.php

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Just to be sure: are you in the actual top level of the repository? (I assume from `.git/info/exclude` that you are, but check by running `git rev-parse --git-dir`, which should print `.git`.)

Comment: What is shown by `git check-ignore -v *`

Comment: @petrpulc oh nice! `.gitignore:10:!wp-content/themes/impact/** page-test.php` So _.gitignore_ is taking precedence over _exclude_. I was able to fix this on _.gitignore_ but the thing is that I need to keep this locally, can't push it to the repo, so it _has_ to be in _exclude_.

Comment: @Petruza added as an answer

Comment: @Petruza Might be better to add `wp-content/themes/impact/page-test.php` rule to `.gitignore` instead of removing the original rule.

Answer (score 2):

**Check if the gitignore rule is not overwritten elsewhere**

Use `git check-ignore -v <PATH>` to list the last rule that affects the ignore status of the `PATH`.

The order of applied gitignore rules is listed in documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

> $HOME/.config/git/ignore, $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, .gitignore

(the first "global gitignore" path may be changed with `git config --global core.excludesfile`)

And the `.gitignore` file in subfolder may overwrite the rules for such folder and its subfolders...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it `/*.php` matches only toplevel php-files.

If you want to ignore all php files:

```
$: cat ./.git/info/exclude
*.php
```

Instead of

```
$: cat ./.git/info/exclude
/*.php
```

If you want to ignore php-file in a certain dir:

```
$: cat ./.git/info/exclude
/wp-content/**/*.php
```

Comment: I don't want to ignore _all_ php files, the whole project is made up of PHP files. The `/*.php` is there just for the top level files.  
The topic of my question is how to ignore specifically this file: `/wp-content/themes/impact/page-test.php`

Comment: Sorry didn't got that: What about /**/page-test.php